# Getting Drive letter from volume id on windows 2016 EC2 -Powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

Is it any simple way to get the EBS volume id for particular drive letter/label?

I am doing this which is just giving the volume IDs but not able to figure out how to get drive letters.

```
# Get Instance ID from the EC2 metadata web service
$instanceID = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id")
# Get a collection of all volumes attached to the instance
$volumes = @(get-ec2volume) | ? { $_.Attachments.InstanceId -eq $instanceID}


# Get a collection of each volume's ID property
$volumeNames = $volumes | %{$_.attachment.device}
$volumeNames
```

Actually, I wanted to tag the ebs volume with particular ec2 instance name: and drive letter.

Comment: thought of using `Get-EC2InstanceMetadata` ?

Comment: `I wanted to tag the ebs volume with particular ec2 instance name: and drive letter.` - what if the EBS volume has multiple drive letters? An EBS volume is a block device, so basically just a disk. It can be formatted to contain multiple file system volumes.

Comment: @arco444 agree but in my case, each volume will act as the single drive only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out.
This script will iterate over all the EBS volumes and add a tag to EBS according to its Disk label. 
You can modify it, as per your need (refer bottom if-else blocks).
The EC2 needs to have proper IAM role to call the New-Ec2 tag API.

```
Start-Transcript -Path C:\cfn\log\Tag-EBS-Volumes.ps1.txt -Append
        # Create a hash table that maps each device to a SCSI target
        $Map = @{"0" = '/dev/sda1'}
        for($x = 1; $x -le 25; $x++) {$Map.add($x.ToString(), [String]::Format("/dev/xvd{0}",[char](97 + $x)))}
        for($x = 78; $x -le 102; $x++) {$Map.add($x.ToString(), [String]::Format("/dev/xvdc{0}",[char](19 + $x)))}

    Try {
        # Use the metadata service to discover which instance the script is running on
        $InstanceId = (Invoke-WebRequest '169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id').Content
        $AvailabilityZone = (Invoke-WebRequest '169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone').Content
        $Region = $AvailabilityZone.Substring(0, $AvailabilityZone.Length -1)

        # Get the list of volumes attached to this instance
        $BlockDeviceMappings = (Get-EC2Instance -Region $Region -Instance $InstanceId).Instances.BlockDeviceMappings
    }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Host "Could not access the AWS API, are your credentials loaded?"  -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }

    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | %{
        $Drive = $_
        # Find the partitions for this drive
        Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition |  Where-Object {$_.Antecedent -eq $Drive.Path.Path} | %{
            $D2P = $_
            # Get details about each partition
            $Partition = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskPartition |  Where-Object {$_.Path.Path -eq $D2P.Dependent}
            # Find the drive that this partition is linked to
            $Disk = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition | Where-Object {$_.Antecedent -in $D2P.Dependent} | %{
                $L2P = $_
                # Get the drive letter for this partition, if there is one
                Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.Path.Path -in $L2P.Dependent}
            }

            $BlockDeviceMapping = $BlockDeviceMappings | Where-Object { $_.DeviceName -eq $Map[$Drive.SCSITargetId.ToString()] }

             If( $Disk.VolumeName -eq "") {
                $tagvalue= "$env:COMPUTERNAME-Root"
             }  ElseIf ($Disk.VolumeName -eq "ABC" )
             {
                $tagvalue= "$env:COMPUTERNAME-ABC"
             }ElseIf ($Disk.VolumeName -eq "DEF" )
             {
                $tagvalue= "$env:COMPUTERNAME-DEF"
             }Else
             {
                $tagvalue= ""
             }

             New-EC2Tag -Resources $BlockDeviceMapping.Ebs.VolumeId -Tags @{ Key = "Name"; Value = $tagvalue } # Add volume name tag that matches VolumeId
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

See: [Listing the Disks Using Windows PowerShell](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-volumes.html#windows-list-disks)

You can just take the relevant portion of the code to display just the drive letter. I do not have the setup to test it.

```
Disk Partitions DriveLetter EbsVolumeId           Device    VirtualDevice VolumeName
---- ---------- ----------- -----------           ------    ------------- ----------
   0          0 N/A         N/A                   xvdca     ephemeral0    N/A
   1          0 N/A         N/A                   xvdcb     ephemeral1    N/A
   2          1 C:          vol-0064aexamplec838a /dev/sda1 root          Windows
   3          0 N/A         vol-02256example8a4a3 xvdf      ebs2          N/A
```

Answer (score 0):

For just a quick lookup you can run the PowerShell command "Get-disk" and use the values in the Serial number column to lookup on the Volumes tab of the EC2 Dashboard in AWS. The serial numbers start with "vol" not "vol-", but if you just use the hex value to match the Volume ID.